# A type named 'SP.Data.ClientsListItem' could not be resolved by the model. When a model is available, each type name must resolve to a valid type

Tags: 2013, 2010, rest, sharepoint-rest-api

I am trying to update a list item using rest api

```
$.ajax({
                    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + url,
                    type: "PATCH",
                    headers: {
                        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                        "__metadata":    {"type": "SP.Data.CaseListItem"},
                        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                        "content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                        "X-Http-Method": "PATCH",
                        "If-Match": olditem.__metadata.etag
                    },
                    data: JSON.stringify(item),
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log(data);
                    },
                    error: function (error) {
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
                    }
                });
```

It throws the below error

> {"readyState":4,"responseText":"{\"error\":{\"code\":\"-1,
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException\",\"message\":{\"lang\":\"en-US\",\"value\":\"A
>   type named 'SP.Data.ClientsListItem' could not be resolved by the
>   model. When a model is available, each type name must resolve to a
>   valid type.\"}}}","responseJSON":{"error":{"code":"-1,
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"A
>   type named 'SP.Data.ClientsListItem' could not be resolved by the
>   model. When a model is available, each type name must resolve to a
>   valid type."}}},"status":400,"statusText":"Bad Request"}

I have passed the modelname in  metadata of header. What should I change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it as below:

```
var item = {
        "__metadata": { "type": "SP.Data.CaseListItem" },
        "Title": "updated title"
    };


    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('CaseList')/items(1)",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        data: JSON.stringify(item),
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
            "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE",
            "If-Match": "*"
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data + " success in updating item");
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hi Gautam, I'm getting the same error. What was the thing you changed in your post compared to the original post?

Answer (score 0):

The first letter of the SharePoint list when passed into item should be capital letter.

In this case the **C** in the name is capital at `"SP.Data.CaseListItem"`.

```
var item = {
    "__metadata": { "type": "SP.Data.CaseListItem" },
    "Title": "updated title"
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check error details, if you are getting this "A type named 'SP.Data.ResourcesListItem' could not be resolved by the model.
When a model is available, each type name must resolve to a valid type."

Here you need to verify "ListItemEntityTypeFullName" name for your list and include it in your code. You can get details using below :

```
GET weburl + "/_api/lists/getbytitle('Resources')?$select=ListItemEntityTypeFullName"
```